# Process virtual memory

Tags: linux, process, virtual, mmap

Can process have a few virtual pages pointing to the same physical address in his same address space ?

I would like that virt_page1---> physical-X
and also that virt_page2 ---> physical-X

How can it be done ? Should it be done from the kernel space ? 
what routines involves ?

if I would like to map shared library like this:

7ff2a90d8000-7ff2a928d000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 4980747                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
7ff2a928d000-7ff2a948d000 ---p 001b5000 08:02 4980747                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
7ff2a948d000-7ff2a9491000 r--p 001b5000 08:02 4980747                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
7ff2a9491000-7ff2a9493000 rw-p 001b9000 08:02 4980747                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so

I see the mapping are private, does it mean that I can't map them again to other virtual address ? should I change the linker for that ?

Update:

While disabling ASLR I did the following:

```
int main(void)
{
  int fd = open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so", O_RDONLY);
  void* f1 = mmap(0, 1748*1024, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE, fd, 0);
  void *f2 = (void*)0x00007ffff7a1a000;

  if (memcmp(f1, f2, 1748*1024) != 0) {
      printf("DIFFER\n");
  }
  while(1);
  return 0;
}
```

This is the .so mapping when there is no ASLR 
00007ffff7a1a000   1748K r-x--  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so

So I mmap the regions of the above to other page & I got this:

00007ffff7e26000   1748K r-x--  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so

While I compare f1 & f2 I see the same data,
is it to say that I have now to virtual regions mapped to the same physical address which is the shared library portion of 1748K ?

Comment: This sounds similar to shared memory or memory mapping. Take a look into those and see if they do what you want.

Comment: Can you point me to an example? is it shared memory within the same process? I don't want to share the pages with other process... I want x1 process with few pages pointing to the same physical memory

Comment: It becomes less and less clear what you are actually trying to achieve.

Comment: I would like to achieve the same mapping of a shared library (only the read only part) via another mapping of virtual addresses, is the example i wrote above achieve it?

Comment: Yes it should work, but why are you doing that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible from the user space. The simplest method is to `mmap` the same file twice.

```
char templ[] = "XXXXXXXX";
int fd = mkstemp(templ);
ftruncate(fd, 1024);
void* f1 = mmap(0, 1024, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
void* f2 = mmap(0, 1024, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
strcpy (f1, "foo bar baz weep quup");
printf ("%p %s\n", f1, (char*)f1);
printf ("%p %s\n", f2, (char*)f2);
```

Comment: But what happens, if the file is a shared library, which is mapped by the linker when the process was loaded ? if I do mmap again to the library (with the exact permission & size) for each of region (which I can read from the /proc/PID/maps) will the new mapping will be exact mapping as the shared library ? How can I test it to see the mapping are the same ? Does memcmp between the regions will be suffice ?

Comment: In shared library the mapping are private, so I can't do it ?

Comment: while disabling ASLR i did int main(void)
{
 int fd = open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so", O_RDONLY);

 void* f1 = mmap(0, 1748*1024, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE, fd, 0);
    void *f2 = (void*)0x00007ffff7a1a000;
    
    if (memcmp(f1, f2, 1748*1024) != 0) {
        printf("DIFFER\n");
    }
    while(1);
 return 0;
}

Comment: For read-only regions nothing of it matters. If you map a read-write region twice privately, memory written via one mapping will not be reflected to the other, which may or may not be what you want.